# What are the star-shaped structures on Titan?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* movie, we saw Thanos' planet Titan.

[image]

In this image, you can see star-shaped structures floating in the air (which actually seem like a signature feature of Titan). They continued to exist there even after destruction of the planet. What are they?

Comment: They look like spaceships.

Comment: The one on the far right seems to be firing a beam at the surface. This could represent some sort of mining activity (and the spaceships would then be mobile drills or extractors), surface-to-ship teleportation (and the ships would then be buses or transports), or weapons.

Answer (score 5):

A direct quote from an [interview](https://www.inverse.com/article/47869-avengers-infinity-war-titan-planet-thanos-backstory-creation-production-design) with Charles wood, the production designer for Infinity war:

> “For those structures, those kind of mad, star-like structures, we
>   looked a lot at windmills,” Wood says. “We wanted to have just simple
>   silhouettes.”

We have no in- or out- of universe explanation for this right now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Infinity War: Titan Consumed](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos:_Titan_Consumed) (intended as a canon description of Thanos' life before the events of the MCU), the structures are '*edifices*', which is a highfalutin way of saying '*a big building*'.

> The building was nondescript and squat, a rare low structure in a city dominated by towering skyscrapers and **floating edifices buoyed aloft by antigravity technology**.

It would seem likely that these stars are simply the space-y equivalent of '*high profile uptown office space*'.